# Calculate duration of all Khan Academy video lectures (under a specific topic at a time) using Python

Tags: python

I am starting with Khan Academy's video lectures / World of Math.
Though i am excited to build my math knowledge from the ground up , i have no idea how much time it will take me. 
Is there some way to write a Python program that

1. goes through say , [Introduction To Algebra](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-intro-to-algebra) ,
2. Finds out which page has notes and which page has a video.
3. If there is a video , notes down its duration ,
4. Keeps on adding duration of videos till the topic is over ,
5. Finally , returns a dictionary with key(The name of the lesson) and the value(The total duration of videos)

I am comparatively new to programming. So i do not have any idea if this is possible. But if it is ? Its really going to fun to do it. 
Plus , it really help me and other people who want to know how much time will they have to invest in Khan Academy.

Comment: Totally possible. Assuming they don't have an API, you can always use https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help. Where should i get started ? I do not even know what an API is , to be honest. I know basic python programming. I'd love to program this. Where should i start? :)